# 4 dimensional choice array in JAGS

Tags: jags

I am trying to run a model in JAGS where I have the following dimensions:

- n Subjects (nSubjects)
- 2 sessions (nSessions)
- 4 conditions (nConditions)
- 42 trials per condition (nTrials)

It is a reinforcement learning model weighting action- and stimulus values.
I started providing jags with 4D (nSubjects x nSessions x nTrials x nConditions) variables. These were variables such as choice, reward magnitudes associated with available options, stimulus and action properties of choice, choice outcome.
JAGS then returned the following error:

```
'Error: 4D and higher dimensional arrays not accepted'
```

I then tried to solve the problem by providing four different variables for the four different conditions. This made the code much more complex and ugly because I resorted to nested ifelse loops (see code below). Does not seem like a proper solution, but might work.
However, I don't know how to handle the fact that my choice data is 4D as well. All other variables are on the right hand side of the equation, so I can work with above-mentioned nested ifelse loops. However, if I provide four different choice varibles, this would not work (as far as I can see, ifelse loops are functions, not a control flow statement, so I cannot state

```
ifelse(c == 1, yCond1 = ..., ifelse(c == 2, yCond2 = ..., ifelse(c == 3, yCond3 = ..., yCond4 = ...)))
```

I also tried to create a new variable within JAGS (where 4D variables can be created, they apparently just cannot be passed to JAGS), like so:

`y[i,s,1:nTrials,c] = ifelse(c == 1,yAct1,ifelse(c==2,yAct2,ifelse(c==3,yStim1,yStim2)))`

But then the problem is that I have NaN values in the choice data which are allowed in the dependent variable (left-hand side of equation), but not in predictor variables (right-hand side) where they now appear.
I assume there must be an elegant way to do this, I just can't come up with one.
Any help greatly appreciated, below my matlab and jags code. (model is still early stage, hierarchical priors etc. still to be implemented)

Cheers, David

```
muLogBetaL=-2.3;muLogBetaU=3.4; %bounds on mean of distribution log beta
sigmaLogBetaL=0.01;sigmaLogBetaU=sqrt(((muLogBetaU-muLogBetaL)^2)/12);%bounds on the std of distribution of log beta

dataStruct = struct(...
            'nConds',           4,...
            'nTrials',          size(choiceComb_Cond1,3),...
            'nSubjs',           numel(subjIDs),...
            'nSessions',        2,...
            'choiceRewCond1',   choiceRewarded_Cond1,...
            'choiceRewCond2',   choiceRewarded_Cond2,...
            'choiceRewCond3',   choiceRewarded_Cond3,...
            'choiceRewCond4',   choiceRewarded_Cond4,...
            'choicePushCond1',  choicePush_Cond1,...
            'choicePushCond2',  choicePush_Cond2,...
            'choicePushCond3',  choicePush_Cond3,...
            'choicePushCond4',  choicePush_Cond4,...
            'choiceYellCond1',  choiceYell_Cond1,...
            'choiceYellCond2',  choiceYell_Cond2,...
            'choiceYellCond3',  choiceYell_Cond3,...
            'choiceYellCond4',  choiceYell_Cond4,...
            'winAmtPushCond1',  winAmtPush_Cond1,...
            'winAmtPushCond2',  winAmtPush_Cond2,...
            'winAmtPushCond3',  winAmtPush_Cond3,...
            'winAmtPushCond4',  winAmtPush_Cond4,...
            'winAmtYellCond1',  winAmtYell_Cond1,...
            'winAmtYellCond2',  winAmtYell_Cond2,...
            'winAmtYellCond3',  winAmtYell_Cond3,...
            'winAmtYellCond4',  winAmtYell_Cond4,...
            'yCond1',           choiceComb_Cond1,...
            'yCond2',           choiceComb_Cond2,...
            'yCond3',           choiceComb_Cond3,...
            'yCond4',           choiceComb_Cond4);

monitorParameters = {'alpha','beta','acw','vPush'};
initStruct.alpha=ones(numel(subjIDs),2,4).*.5;
initStruct.beta=ones(numel(subjIDs),2).*.02;
initStruct.acw=ones(numel(subjIDs),2,4).*.02;
init0(1) = initStruct;% a structure array that has the initial values for all latent variables for each chain

doParallel = 0;
modelName = 'modelRL';
nChains = 1;
nBurnin = 500;
nSamples = 5000;
nThin = 1;
doDIC = 0;

fprintf( 'Running JAGS ...\n' ); % display
[samples, stats] = matjags( ...
    dataStruct, ...                           % Observed data
    fullfile(pwd, [modelName '.txt']), ...    % File that contains model definition
    init0 , ...                               % Initial values for latent variables
    1 , ...                                   % which copy of matjags to run
    'doparallel' , doParallel, ...            % Parallelization flag
    'nchains', nChains,...                    % Number of MCMC chains
    'nburnin', nBurnin,...                    % Number of burnin steps
    'nsamples', nSamples, ...                 % Number of samples to extract
    'thin', nThin, ...                        % Thinning parameter
    'dic', doDIC, ...                         % Do the DIC?
    'monitorparams', monitorParameters, ...   % List of latent variables to monitor
    'savejagsoutput' , 0 , ...                % Save command line output produced by JAGS?
    'verbosity' , 2 , ...                     % 0=do not produce any output; 1=minimal text output; 2=maximum text output
    'cleanup' , 0 ,...                        % clean up of temporary files?
    'rndseed',1);                             % Randomise seed; 0=no; 1=yes
```

```
model{
        for(i in 1:nSubjs){
            for(s in 1:nSessions){
                for(c in 1:nConds){

                    # STARTING VALUES FOR FIRST TRIAL
                    # Reward probability estimate for pushing/yellow
                    pPushRew[i,s,1,c] = .5
                    pYellRew[i,s,1,c] = .5

                    # Expected values
                    vPush[i,s,1,c] = ifelse(c == 1,
                        pPushRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtPushCond1[i,s,1],
                        ifelse(c == 2,
                            pPushRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtPushCond2[i,s,1],
                            ifelse(c == 3,
                                pPushRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtPushCond3[i,s,1],
                                pPushRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtPushCond4[i,s,1])))
                    vYell[i,s,1,c] = ifelse(c == 1,
                        pYellRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtYellCond1[i,s,1],
                        ifelse(c == 2,
                            pYellRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtYellCond2[i,s,1],
                            ifelse(c == 3,
                                pYellRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtYellCond3[i,s,1],
                                pYellRew[i,s,1,c] * winAmtYellCond4[i,s,1])))
                    vPull[i,s,1,c] = ifelse(c == 1,
                        (1-pPushRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond1[i,s,1]),
                        ifelse(c == 2,
                            (1-pPushRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond2[i,s,1]),
                            ifelse(c == 3,
                                (1-pPushRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond3[i,s,1]),
                                (1-pPushRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond4[i,s,1]))))
                    vBlue[i,s,1,c] = ifelse(c == 1,
                        (1-pYellRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond1[i,s,1]),
                        ifelse(c == 2,
                            (1-pYellRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond2[i,s,1]),
                            ifelse(c == 3,
                                (1-pYellRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond3[i,s,1]),
                                (1-pYellRew[i,s,1,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond4[i,s,1]))))

                    # Weighted Action-Color combination value
                    AC[i,s,1,c,1] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPull[i,s,1,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vBlue[i,s,1,c])
                    AC[i,s,1,c,2] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPull[i,s,1,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vYell[i,s,1,c])
                    AC[i,s,1,c,3] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPush[i,s,1,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vBlue[i,s,1,c])
                    AC[i,s,1,c,4] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPush[i,s,1,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vYell[i,s,1,c])

                    # choice probability for each action-color combination
                    pAC[i,s,1,c,1] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,1])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,2])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,3])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,4]))
                    pAC[i,s,1,c,2] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,2])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,1])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,3])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,4]))
                    pAC[i,s,1,c,3] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,3])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,1])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,2])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,4]))
                    pAC[i,s,1,c,4] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,4])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,1])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,2])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,1,c,3]))

                    # realizing choice
                    y[i,s,1,c] ~ dcat(pAC[i,s,1,c,1:4]) #THIS DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE 4D ARRAY

                    # LOOP OVER TRIALS
                    for(t in 2:nTrials){ 
                        #updating of reward probability estimate for pushing
                        pPushRew[i,s,t,c] = ifelse(c==1,
                            ifelse(choicePushCond1[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond1[i,s,t-1]-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond1[i,s,t-1]-1))-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c])),
                            ifelse(c==2,
                                ifelse(choicePushCond2[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                    pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond2[i,s,t-1]-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                    pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond2[i,s,t-1]-1))-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c])),
                                ifelse(c==3,
                                    ifelse(choicePushCond3[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                        pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond3[i,s,t-1]-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                        pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond3[i,s,t-1]-1))-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c])),
                                    ifelse(choicePushCond4[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                        pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond4[i,s,t-1]-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                        pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond4[i,s,t-1]-1))-pPushRew[i,s,t-1,c])))))

                        #updating of reward probability estimate for yellow
                        pYellRew[i,s,t,c] = ifelse(c==1,
                            ifelse(choiceYellCond1[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond1[i,s,t-1]-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond1[i,s,t-1]-1))-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c])),
                            ifelse(c==2,
                                ifelse(choiceYellCond2[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                    pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond2[i,s,t-1]-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                    pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond2[i,s,t-1]-1))-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c])),
                                ifelse(c==3,
                                    ifelse(choiceYellCond3[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                        pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond3[i,s,t-1]-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                        pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond3[i,s,t-1]-1))-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c])),
                                    ifelse(choiceYellCond4[i,s,t-1] == 1, 
                                        pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*(choiceRewCond4[i,s,t-1]-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c]),
                                        pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c] + alpha[i,s,c]*((-1*(choiceRewCond4[i,s,t-1]-1))-pYellRew[i,s,t-1,c])))))

                        # EV for pushing/yellow
                        vPush[i,s,t,c] = ifelse(c==1,
                            pPushRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtPushCond1[i,s,t],
                            ifelse(c==2,
                                pPushRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtPushCond2[i,s,t],
                                ifelse(c==3,
                                    pPushRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtPushCond3[i,s,t],
                                    pPushRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtPushCond4[i,s,t])))
                        vYell[i,s,t,c] = ifelse(c==1,
                            pYellRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtYellCond1[i,s,t],
                            ifelse(c==2,
                                pYellRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtYellCond2[i,s,t],
                                ifelse(c==3,
                                    pYellRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtYellCond3[i,s,t],
                                    pYellRew[i,s,t,c] * winAmtYellCond4[i,s,t])))


                        # EV for pulling/blue
                        vPull[i,s,t,c] = ifelse(c==1,
                            (1-pPushRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond1[i,s,t]),
                            ifelse(c==2,
                                (1-pPushRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond2[i,s,t]),
                                ifelse(c==3,
                                    (1-pPushRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond3[i,s,t]),
                                    (1-pPushRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtPushCond4[i,s,t]))))
                        vBlue[i,s,t,c] = ifelse(c==1,
                            (1-pYellRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond1[i,s,t]),
                            ifelse(c==2,
                                (1-pYellRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond2[i,s,t]),
                                ifelse(c==3,
                                    (1-pYellRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond3[i,s,t]),
                                    (1-pYellRew[i,s,t,c]) * (100-winAmtYellCond4[i,s,t]))))

                        # Weighted Action-Color combination value
                        AC[i,s,t,c,1] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPull[i,s,t,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vBlue[i,s,t,c])
                        AC[i,s,t,c,2] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPull[i,s,t,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vYell[i,s,t,c])
                        AC[i,s,t,c,3] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPush[i,s,t,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vBlue[i,s,t,c])
                        AC[i,s,t,c,4] = (acw[i,s,c] * vPush[i,s,t,c]) + ((1-acw[i,s,c]) * vYell[i,s,t,c])

                        # choice probability for each action-color combination
                        pAC[i,s,t,c,1] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,1])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,2])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,3])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,4]))
                        pAC[i,s,t,c,2] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,2])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,1])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,3])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,4]))
                        pAC[i,s,t,c,3] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,3])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,1])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,2])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,4]))
                        pAC[i,s,t,c,4] = exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,4])/(exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,1])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,2])+exp(beta[i,s]*AC[i,s,t,c,3]))

                        # realizing choice
                        y[i,s,t,c] ~ dcat(pAC[i,s,t,c,1:4]) #THIS DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE 4D ARRAY
                     }

                }

                # PRIORS
                for(c in 1:nConds){
                    alpha[i,s,c] ~ dbeta(1,1)

                    acw[i,s,c] ~ dbeta(1,1)
                } #end condition specific priors
                beta[i,s] ~ dnorm(.001,0.03) T(0.0001,.045)
            } #end session loop
        } #end subject loop
    } #end model
```

Answer (score 1):

First off Jags uses NA, not NaN, and the NA can appear in the right-hand side of an equation, it just cannot be a parameter for a random variable.

In relation to the array issue, code wise it is a lot to work through, and I don't have a great idea of what your code is trying to do, but one great solution conceptually within JAGS when working with > 2d data you are passing in, is to figure out how to represent that same data within a matrix. Sometimes referred to as making wide data long. So in this case you would create a matrix, and if I understand correctly you would have one for the stimulus, and one for the action taken. There would be (n x 2 x 4 x 42) rows and the columns would be the stimulus/action (depending on the table) in column 1, the subject in column 2, session in column 3, and so on. You then only need 1 loop in JAGS to go from 1:nrow of this matrix and can just select variables from the respective columns as you need them.

The series of ifelse cases is I think a separate problem not solved by the above solution.
For example, in
`y[i,s,1:nTrials,c] = ifelse(c ==1,yAct1,ifelse(c==2,yAct2,ifelse(c==3,yStim1,yStim2)))`
If I am understanding that correctly you are assigning a certain variable (some yAct or yStim) to the array based on c. Instead create a vector
`X=c(yAct1,yAct2,yStim1,yStim2)` where c here is to create a vector, not your variable c,
and assign to the matrix by indexing X with c
`y[i,s,1:nTrials,c]= X[c]`

I know these answers won't help fully solve your code since there was too much to go through there, but hopefully this conceptually helps you understand what improvements could be made. Let me know if you need anymore help.